# C code, what am I missing for this control statement program?

Tags: c

I am working on a program. This is what I am attempting to achieve;
The program should present a menu of pay rates from which to choose. Use a switch to select the pay rate. The beginning of a run should look something like this:
[image]

If choices 1 through 4 are selected, the program should request the hours worked. The program should recycle until 5 is entered. If something other than choices 1 through 5 is entered, the program should remind the user what the proper choices are and then recycle. Use #defined constants for the various earning rates and tax rates.

This is the code I have so far, what am I missing?;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int choice, hour;
float taxe, total;

printf("****************************************************************\n");
printf("\nEnter the number corresponding to the desired pay rate or action");
printf("\n1)$8.75/hr");
printf("\n2)$9.33/hr");
printf("\n3)$10.00/hr");
printf("\n4)$11.20hr");
printf("\n5)Quit");
printf("**********************************************************\n");

scanf("%d", &choice);

printf("Please enter number of hours: ");
scanf("%d", &hour);

switch(choice){
case 1:
    total = 8.75* hour;
    break;
case 2:
    total = 9.33*hour;
    break;
case 3:
    total = 10.00*hour;
    break;
case 4:
    total = 11.20*hour;
    break;
case 5:
     break;
return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: This sounds like homework to me, is it?

Comment: @KlasLindbäck thank you, this makes sense. Do I need to just use  "while" loop, or does it need to be a "do while" loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what am I missing?

What you are missing is the actual iteration.

> The program should recycle until 5 is entered.

This means that you have to do all your work inside a loop, which will check each time if the value read is `5`, which you need in order to stop iterating. You can use one of the following ways :

1. ***while loop:***

   ```
   scanf("%d", &choice);
   while (choice != 5)
   {
       ....
       switch(choice){
           ....
       }
       ....
    scanf("%d", &choice);
   }
   ```
2. ***for loop:***

   ```
   for (scanf("%d", &choice); choice != 5; scanf("%d", &choice);)
   {
       ....
       switch(choice){
           ....
       }
       ....
   }
   ```
3. ***do-while loop:***

   ```
   do{
       scanf("%d", &choice);
       ....
       switch(choice){
           ....
       }
       ....
   }while(choice != 5);
   ```

Comment: @user3247128 I am glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

You did'nt used a loop. It can't recycle until 5 entered.

After taking the choice, insert a while loop :

```
while(choice != 5){
```

and process normally your switch, ignoring the 5 value, adding a "default" case if another value is entered.

If you want the total program to recycles, use a do{} while(); starting on your printf, ending afgter the switch.

Comment: Always depends of the use case. Follow these questions to know what loop to use. After just thing about the use case, you'll understand where to put it.

Do your know how many loop the program has to do ? => for loop
Does the program have to go ONE or MORE time in the loop  ? => do while loop
Else, while loop. With the while, the program can just break if the statement is not true. With the do while, the program has to do the statement one time, or more it the statement is true.

Answer (score 1):

you have yo use do while loop here like below

```
 do
 {
    clrscr();
    printf("****************************************************************\n");
    printf("\nEnter the number corresponding to the desired pay rate or action");
    printf("\n1)$8.75/hr");
    printf("\n2)$9.33/hr");
    printf("\n3)$10.00/hr");
    printf("\n4)$11.20hr");
    printf("\n5)Quit");
    printf("**********************************************************\n");

    scanf("%d", &choice);

    printf("Please enter number of hours: ");
    scanf("%d", &hour);

    switch(choice){
    case 1:
        total = 8.75* hour;
        break;
    case 2:
        total = 9.33*hour;
        break;
    case 3:
        total = 10.00*hour;
        break;
    case 4:
        total = 11.20*hour;
        break;
    case 5:
         break;
    default :
        printf("\n please enter proper choice");
        getch();
    }
 }while(choice !=5);
```